# CheckBox does not appear when zoom out on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Checkboxes doesn't appear properly **when using Chrome** and zoom out to 75% or less. I'm also using AngularJS latest version. In **FireFox** and **Internet Explorer** they appear properly.

I tried to fix this problem with:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance:checkbox;
}
```

but this doesn't help.

**Here how it looks like:**
[image: Here is on 75%. Some times the ticks does not appear at all]

The checkboxes are custom and there is 1 span and inside 2 divs. Here is the code:

```css
.ckeckmark { 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 18px; 
  height: 18px; 
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}` 
.ckeckmark > .stem { 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 1px; 
  height: 11px; 
  background-color: #1C4A9E; 
  left: 8px; 
  top: 2px; 
} 
.ckeckmark > .kick {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 5px; 
  height: 1px; 
  background-color: #1C4A9E; 
  left: 3px; 
  top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<span ng-class="{ckeckmark: resident}">
  <div class="stem"></div>
  <div class="kick"></div>
</span>
```

`.stem` and `.kick` are 2 divs next to each other inside `.checkmark` span class.

After research i noticed that Google Chrome displays a web page OK at 100% zoom (and above) but when the zoom level is less than 100% (e.g. 90%) padding get changed. A  moves from the right-hand-side of the screen to the left hand side.
 Any help/suggestions?

Comment: If you don't post code, we can't test..

Comment: What  code ? I said i'm using angular and the code is :<span ng-class="{ckeckmark: resident}"></span>

Comment: Looks like you are using custom checkboxes, aren't you? Lets say in others words, how do you think we could test this?

Comment: I edited my question with code. Sorry about missing the code

Comment: try implementing working code

Comment: It works on Firefox and Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I popped this into a fiddle and I think I saw your problem.  It took zooming out to 33% before the checkmark disappeared at jsfiddle as opposed to your 75%.

The solution I used was to use borders on the actual stem and kick instead of using a background on those elements.

```
.ckeckmark { 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 18px; 
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.stem { 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 1px; 
  height: 11px; 
  border-left: 1px solid red; 
  left: 8px; 
  top: 2px; 
} 
.kick {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 5px; 
  height: 7px; 
  border-top: 1px solid red; 
  left: 3px; 
  top: 12px;
}
```

I have not tested this in other browsers, but I zoomed out all the way to 25% and I still saw the checkmark.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1658/

Comment: It fits, thank you so much. I already change the whole check box with Input Tag and CSS only, without div tags, but however i appreciate your help and efforts . Thanks again !